# Are there any balance issues with familiar from the Find Familiar spell to be of the elemental creature type (instead of celestial, fey, or fiend)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, house-rules, familiars

The spell [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) allows a character to summon a familiar, which is a spirit of creature type celestial, fey or fiend. From the spell's description (PHB, p. 240):

> You gain the service of a familiar, a spirit that takes the form of an animal [...] the familiar has the statistics of the chosen form, though it is a **celestial, fey, or fiend (your choice)** instead of a beast.

Would there be any balance issues with allowing the familiar to be of the elemental creature type instead (meaning, adjusting the above description to read "**celestial, elemental, fey, or fiend (your choice)**" instead)?

Elemental creatures are affected in the same way as celestial/fey/fiend creatures by other spells such as *protection from evil and good*, *forbiddance*, and *banishment* (being permanently banished to their home plane rather than just stuck in a demiplane for 1 minute), etc, so being an elemental shouldn't allow the creature to bypass that which would affect a RAW *find familiar* familiar.

That would have been the main thing that I would suspect might affect balance, but I can't think of a spell that affects *only* celestials, fiends and fey, *but not* elementals. And I don't feel like the concept of an elemental spirit creature being summoned as a familiar goes against the narrative theme of the spell either.

Are there any odd interactions with an elemental familiar that might make it more or less powerful than, say, a celestial familiar? My intention is for this to not affect the balance whatsoever.

Comment: I'd also be interested in this, as well as other 'outsider' types like aberration, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## No, There's no Major Difference.

Creature type in 5e is rarely referenced, and it is mostly used as flavor. However, I did find a couple of effects that will effect an elemental differently.

- The Paladin's Divine Sense detects "the location of any celestial, fiend, or undead within 60 feet of you that is not behind total cover" (PHB, p. 84)
- The Ranger's Primeval Awareness senses "whether the following types of creatures are present within 1 mile of you (or within up to 6 miles if you are in your favored terrain): Aberrations, Celestials, Dragons, Elementals, fey, Fiends, and Undead." (PHB, p. 93)

These are relatively minor, and generally will not affect the balance of the game.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Good first answer, take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to the paladin; that reminds me of the Oath of the Ancients ability, Turn the Faithless (PHB, p. 87): "_You can use your Channel Divinity to utter ancient words that are painful for **fey and fiends** to hear. As an action, you present your holy symbol, and each **fey or fiend** within 30 feet of you that can hear you must make a Wisdom saving throw. On a failed save, the creature is turned for 1 minute or until it takes damage._" Luckily, this and Divine Sense (from your answer) excludes either celestial or fey, so an elemental familiar should be fine as well.